# Check CapsLock over RDP connection

Tags: windows, keyboard, rdp

I tried two approaches to reading the state of a keyboard's CapsLock key.
The first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.iskeylocked.aspx 
And the second: k_bb2fe024f8a71424996db6d9af08c1fc_*settingNewSkin*_19">http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/38617-get-the-state-of-capslock/page_*k*_bb2fe024f8a71424996db6d9af08c1fc_*settingNewSkin*_19

Now both of these approaches work on my local Windows machine. That is, they show the Keyboard's CapsLock state accurately.

Running the same programs on a computer that connects to windows remote desktop using rdp, the program doesn't work, and only shows the CapsLock key to be off.

Is there a special windows method I have to call when checking the CapsLock key over RDP?

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation has shown that it's rdesktop, not RDP that's responsible for the CapsLock failure.

Comment: But what IS responsible? It looks like capslock event is lost somewhere on mstsc, but the Internets are silent on that.